# Is it possible to detect push-notification arrival?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I can catch an event of opening push-notification via

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

but user may receive push-notification, but doesn't open it. So is it possible to handle an arrival of push-notification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you are referring to in your question is called only if a push notification was received while the app was running in the foreground. In order to handle push notifications that were used to launch the application (or bring the app back from the background), you need to check the "options" dictionary within your appDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

To answer your additional question - no, if the user didn't open your app with a push notification, there's no way you can gain access to it.

Comment: @stavash  is there any way get text from push notification when app is in background ?

Comment: Only if the user opened the app using the arriving notification. It will then be available within the userInfo dictionary of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: